# Assign objects to properties inside for each doen't work

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, foreach, datasource

i what to render a list of my userControl "GaleriaDetalhe" inside a for each statement on a asp.net page. by this way it returns me this error:

*Cannot create an object of type 'SKortal.ImageGalery.ImageGalery' from its string representation '<% getGaleria(g) %>' for the 'DataSource' property.*

How can i assign directly the foreach currentobject to the datasource property of my usercontrol? How?

```
<%@ Register src="GaleriaDetalhe.ascx" tagname="GaleriaDetalhe" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<%  For Each g As ImageGalery In DataSource%>
<uc1:GaleriaDetalhe ID="GDetail" runat="server" DataSource="<% g %>" />
<% Next%>
```

to be more specific, what i pretend is to know how can i assign objects to properties in markup?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

This is not a correct way to create the list. Ether use a repeater, ether load the control every time you needded on your lise using the `Page.LoadControl("GaleriaDetalhe.ascx");`

**Use a repeater to render a list of your Controls.**

Comment: OK, i Know that, usually i use a repeater!!, this is an experience, i'm trying to find som new solutions more "viewstateless". my preocupation is to know how to assign objects to properties in markup. without the databind!

Comment: @Flavio, disable the viewstate if won viewstateless, or else you need to load your control every time on your loop, and manually run it and initialized it.

Comment: is there some way to assign objects to properties of user controls? (My interest in on that!, forget about the for each!) on the markup way, dont pretend overrides the databind!

Comment: @Flavio every public val/object on your control can assign that after you create it using the LoadControl.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create your user controls in code, and add them to a `PlaceHolder`. The trick is to use `Reference` rather than `Register` (in the ASPX page) as this allows you to create the user controls just like any other object without needing `Page.LoadControl` (the controls appear inside the ASP namespace). You can then either pass objects into their constructor, or create public properties within them.

My [blog post here](http://codeoverload.wordpress.com/2010/09/05/asp-net-creating-user-controls-programatically/) shows the steps.